# How to always show top bar in Xcode 11.3?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using the latest Xcode 11.3 with a storyboard. When open `.storyboard` files in a new window, the bar at the top of the window (i.e. the bar in the picture below) not shows up by default. It makes it difficult to add views or objects to the storyboard.

Is it possible to change this behavior? Or is there any convenient way to add views or objects to the storyboard in a separate window?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about iOS 13 or Xcode 11.3? There is no version of Xcode 13.

Comment: @HardikS Yes, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in Xcode 'View' section which is show/hide Toolbar. you can go with that otherwise `Alt + Cmd + T` is also a shortcut to show/hide the toolbar.

[image]